# Contar posiciones de un campo SQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

¿Como logro contar cada posición de este array?
Estuve trabajando con consultas SQL lo que pasa es q no logro obtener las posiciones[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes consultarla normalmente y luego usas la función nativa de Php llamada [explode](http://php.net/manual/es/function.explode.php)

```
$query = "SELECT `resultados` FROM tabla";
```

Luego que obtienes la consulta, aplicas explode:

```
$result = $conn->query($query);

$result = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);

// Obtengo un array con cada elemento separado por paid ("|")
    $resultados = explode('|', $result);

$cantidad_resultados = count($resultados);
```

Ve la documentación de explode para mejor compresión.

Answer (score 0):

Si lo que necesitas es realizar la suma desde tu SQL, puedes intentar

```
SELECT  SUM((LEN(campo] ) - LEN(REPLACE(campo, 'RAISERROR 50000', '')))/LEN('RAISERROR 50000')) as suma FROM    table
```

Pero si lo que necesitas es hacerlo desde tu PHP

Puedes usar:

> str_word_count()

Ejemplo:

```
$cadena = "Esto es una prueba para contar palabras";
echo "$cadena";
```

//saco el número de palabras con el parámtero '0'

```
echo "Hay ".str_word_count($cadena, 0). " palabras en la cadena '$cadena'";
```

//guardo las palabras en un array

```
$array_cadena = str_word_count($cadena, 1);
```

//saco cada elemento del array

```
foreach ($array_cadena as $palabra) {
echo $palabra . " ";
}
```